# Finding this math YouTube channel

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, education, 3d

So last year, by chance I found a YouTube channel while I was looking for videos related to 3D geometry and multivariable calculus.

The channel had very few subscribers and most video had views only in the hundreds. The channel had amazing animation and it had animated mascots. A guy wearing funky glasses appears in the beginning of every video and speaks in an animated old TV set.

Can anybody help me find that channel please.
Thank you.

Edit: Apparently no mascots or funky glasses, it's just my memory.

Comment: This is probably not the one you are thinking of but [here is a mathematics/economics/statistics channel with great animations](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKzJFdi57J53Vr_BkTfN3uQ)

Comment: There is also, of course, [3blue1brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw), but I don't think his animations are 3D, so probably not what you are thinking of

Comment: Yea, I have one clue though, the videos look similar to https://www.youtube.com/user/EugeneKhutoryansky that but I remember them to look much more cleaner

Comment: Specifically, he was teaching about the slope of a line in 3D or something like that.

Comment: I think his introductory video was actually for calculus or vectors I'm not sure. It was a series of video btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're thinking of Prof. Robert Ghrist's excellent "Calculus BLUE" series on multivariable calculus, perhaps in particular [this video about lines in 3D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a06KMRNe6V4&list=PL8erL0pXF3JYm7VaTdKDaWc8Q3FuP8Sa7&index=6).

He has more materials to go with the youtube videos at [the Calculus BLUE site](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/calculus.html) , as well as materials for other topics across his site. He deserves more attention, in my opinion.